# Optimize function defined with Nintegrate

Tags: functions, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I would like to optimize evaluation of the function defined as an integral:

```
f[x_]:= NIntegrate[g[s],{s,0,x}]
```

the function g[x] can be an Interpolating function. The problem is that when I want to generate a Table of points

```
Table[f[x],{x,0.,200.,10.}]
```

function f[x] need to reintegrate the previous domain which is a waste of time because I calculated this value previously. I am thinking of a function definition that stores limits of integration and the value of the NIntegrate and when I call it for different argument it just integrates the missing part and adds it to the stored variable. For example:

```
f[2.] = NIntegrate[g[s],{s,0.,2.}]
f[4.] = NIntegrate[g[s],{s,2.,4.}] + f[2.]
f[3.] = f[4.] - NIntegrate[g[s],{s,3.,4.}]
```

With this function definition creating a list of values would be much faster. Is something like this possible in Mathematica 11.0?

Comment: If `g` ***is*** an `InterpolatingFunction` (as opposed to merely "can be"), then use `Integrate[g[s], s]`, which yields a `G[s]` where `G` is the integral (an `InterpolatingFunction`) of `g` such that `G[a] == 0`, where `{a, b}` is the domain of `g`.

Comment: Another approach could be to use `NDSolve` instead of `NIntegrate`.

Comment: An excelent answer can be found here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130617/23248

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you seek of remembering subcalculations is called **memoization** ([Wolfram Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)) and could be implemented like this:

```
delta = 10.;
f2[x_]:= f2[x] = f2[x - delta] + NIntegrate[g[s],{s,x - delta,x}];
f2[0.] = 0;
ans3 = Table[f2[x], {x, 0., 200., delta}]
```

As a demo, I will use `g = FunctionInterpolation[Exp[x/200], {x, 0, 200}]` here.

However this does actually **not** run any faster than your original proposition (at least for the `g` I chose here), because `NIntegrate` is still called as many times as before. Just because the intervals you integrate over are smaller, does not mean `NIntegrate` will necessarily run much faster, because it uses adaptive algorithms to subdivide the interval it's given in every case.

---

When `g` is an `InterpolatingFunction` then `Integrate[g[s], s]` should be possible for symbolic `s`. So you can just do

```
int = Integrate[g[s], s];
a = int /. s -> 0;
ans1 = Table[int - a /. s -> x, {x, 0., 200., 10.}]
```

With `g = FunctionInterpolation[Exp[x/200], {x, 0, 200}]` the code

```
f[x_]:= NIntegrate[g[s],{s,0,x}];
ans2 = Table[f[x],{x,0.,200.,10.}]
```

takes 0.03 second to complete, while my suggestion takes 0.0006 seconds. Note however that `ans1 - ans2` have some terms of order $10^{-6}$, which you may or may not need to think about.