# Saving NIntegrate for many intermediate uses

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration

I need a bit of help speeding up this code:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{I k'[s] == 20 (s k[s] - (1 - s) (1 - k[s]) (1 + k[s])),
               k[0] == 1/2}, k, {s, 0, 1}];

func[s_] := Abs[ NIntegrate[(1 - sl) (1 - sol@sl),{sl,0,s}]];
Plot[func[s], {s, 0, 1}]
```

So, `Plot` evaluates `NIntegrate` multiple times, and wastes a lot of time redoing calculations from zero to s in small increments.

Is there a way to run `NIntegrate` once from beginning to end and store its intermediate values in something like an interpolating function?

I am using Mathematica 10, and `StepMonitor` is not a valid option for `NIntegrate`. :(

Comment: Very closely related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126999/optimize-function-defined-with-nintegrate/). You can `Integrate` `InterpolatingFunction`s just fine, and in this case, you can make an `InterpolatingFunction` from your integrand using `FunctionInterpolation`, i.e. `integral = 
 Integrate[
  FunctionInterpolation[(1 - sl) (1 - sol@sl), {sl, 0, 1}][s], s]`. This you can plot: `Plot[Abs[integral], {s, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Indeed very close!!! I will post there a link to Akku's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at Help->Find Selekcted Function->NIntegrate->Properties and Relations ->"NDSolve can be used instead of NIntegrate".
Using NDSolve you only once calculate an Interpolated Function up to your max s, that can be used for Plot.

```
      NDSolve[{D[f[sl], sl] == (1 - sl) (1 - sol@sl), f[0] == 0}, f, 
            {sl, 0, smax}][[1, 1]]
```

Comment: Excelent! I looked up the documentation but missed that one. In ordder to improve your answer a bit i suggest using NDSolveValue instead of NDSolve. This way you dont need the [[1,1]] and needs less code to plot and manipulate the interpolating function too.